# .NET application server

Tags: .net, web-services, web-applications

Are there any .NET apllication servers (like Java EE ones - JBoss, WebSphere and alike) ?

Answer (score 7):

There is no clear concept of `Application Server` in .NET, since the .NET framework is quite integrated in the OS. In web applications, the role of `Application Server` would be split into IIS and Windows itself. To summarize: .NET Framework is so rich that it already provides many of the functionality applications may need.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from [IIS](http://www.iis.net/)?

Apache has a [.NET](http://mod-aspdotnet.sourceforge.net/mod_aspdotnet.html) module you can use.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, **IIS** with its Integrated Pipeline and the .NET Framework is the closest we get.

Going forward, this is the role intended for [Windows Server AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I've seen for .NET is the **OutSystems Platform** ([www.outsystems.com](http://www.outsystems.com)).

We used it at the last place I worked to develop, deploy, change and manage a set of internal web-based business applications. It's an application server in the sense that it takes care of staging applications between environments, publishing to multiple front-end servers, upgrading databases, rolling back, centralising application configuration, logs, monitoring performance etc.

The platform is also model-based, so you only need to drop down into C# when you need to extend the capabilities of the platform. The big benefit you get is because it handles the whole lifecycle of your applications (being a full application server), everything is much quicker.

Declaration: I liked it so much, I now work for OutSystems in the UK!

Answer (score 0):

There is NetFluid ( http://www.netfluid.org )

1. Runs on Mono
2. Serve an incredible numer of request
3. Static members are really static so you can have an object shared by all the pages and
   live until the server is alive.(ex: a SMTPServer object static inside a webmail page)